# JSON string failing in JSON.parse but passes JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, javascript, json, json.net

My C# class is

```
public class Man
{
    public string name {get; set;}
}
```

String to deserialize is like this

```
var content = "[{name: \"john\"}]"
```

Now before saving to db, I was doing check that if string can be deserialized to C# object then store it. This check passes

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Man>>(content)
```

So I save this string in db but when I do JSON.parse over saved string in javascript, it crashes with error

```
JSON.parse("[{name: \"john\"}]")
SyntaxError: Unexpected token n
```

Now I understand that by surrounding quotes around key ("name") this can be solved. This is correct string that works in both JSON.parse and JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

```
var content = "[{\"name\": \"john\"}]
```

Problem is I have many such ill formed strings in db already that crash on JSON.parse only. What is the best way to convert such strings so that JSON.parse will work? Something better than string.replace
Please note that actual strings are quite big and complicated compared to example given.

Comment: First deserialize than serialize again with json.net

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `using Newtonsoft.Json;` it will DeserializeObject object even your json data in `var content = "[{name: \"john\"}]"` format.

value contains data like :`{StyleId:"1710","SelectedItemToColorMap":{1391:"583",21531:"7733"}}`

```
 var jsondata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value);
```

after DeserializeObject the jsondata look like

```
{
  "StyleId": "1710",
  "SelectedItemToColorMap": {
    "1391": "583",
    "21531": "7733"
  }
}
```

Comment: you can DeserializeObject and then use it on JSON.parse();